# Regex Checking if String Contains Two or More Instances of Words from a Set

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to see if there are 2 or more of any words in a set in a given string.

If the set is [cat, dog] then:

"cat in the hat" - false

"cat and dog" - true

"cat and cat" - true

I tried these, but they don't work correctly:

```
\bcat\b|\bdog\b{2,}
(\bcat\b|\bdog\b){2,}
```

is this query possible with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Pure Regex**

```
(?:.*(?:\b(?:cat|dog)\b)){2}
```

If there is a match, it is `True` that two or more of the words are present.

If you want to be a purist about a regex that in itself constitutes a Boolean assertion (no matching of characters), we can wrap this in a lookahead:

```
^(?=(?:.*(?:\b(?:cat|dog)\b)){2})
```

**Option 2: Count Matches**

If you are using a programming language, this pseudocode:

```
WordsRegex = \b(?:cat|dog)\b
MatchCount = count matches(WordsRegex, string)
TwoOrMore = ( MatchCount > 1)
```

Comment: FYI Added pure regex options.

Comment: not sure what you mean by asserting without matching - I cannot get the second example to work. The first one works fine though. thanks

Comment: `(?:\b(?:cat|dog)\b.*){2}` should be faster for inputs that don't contain any cats nor dogs due to less backtracking

Comment: That's true, @deathApril. I haven't tried to optimize this small pattern, otherwise I would probably have gone for something like `(?:\b(?:cat|dog)\b).*(?:\b(?:cat|dog)\b)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a simple true/false result for the match, or would you like to actually capture the words that match?

Some regex languages, like PCRE, allow for "pattern repeat" with the (?[some number]) format:

```
(?=(cat|dog).*(?1))
```

This looks for either `cat` or `dog` and then (due to the `(?1)`) looks for `cat` or `dog` again. [Example 1](http://regex101.com/r/nD6pO2/1).

If you wish to capture the pattern (either the entire thing, or the individual words), you can use one of:

```
((cat|dog).*((?2)))
```

[Example 2](http://regex101.com/r/nD6pO2/2)

or

```
(?:(cat|dog).*((?1)))
```

[Example 3](http://regex101.com/r/nD6pO2/3)

Example 2 captures the entire group in the `\1` reference, with the captured words in `\2` and `\3`, respectively.

Example 3 doesn't capture the entire group, but it does capture the words in `\1` and `\2`, respectively.

Other languages (Javascript, Python) may handle this differently, so you may not have access to the `(?1)` reference.